# Text content going out of card in Angular Material 2

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2, ngfor

[image: Card content going out of card]

I am using ngFor to display a list of notes, it works fine when there is space a few letters, but if someone added a long string withought any space in it, the text of the card goes beyond its borders and create a horizontal scroll bar which goes as long as until the card text ends. How do I make the text content to break automatically when it has reached the border of the card?

My *ngFor Card code looks like this

```
<div class="col-md-3 eachCard" *ngFor="let note of allNotes">
    <md-card>
      <md-card-content>{{ note.noteText }}</md-card-content>
          <md-card-actions>
           <md-icon class="actionIcons" (click)="edit(note)">create</md-icon>
              <md-icon class="actionIcons" (click)="delete(note)">clear</md-icon>
          </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the word-break CSS property :

The word-break property in CSS can be used to change when line breaks ought to occur. Normally, line breaks in text can only occur in certain spaces, like when there is a space or a hyphen.

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;

 /* Non standard for WebKit */
    word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
```

All credits to [this excellent site.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)

Comment: That fixed it. Thank's a lot, didn't knew such a css property existed!